# Let $ T: V \to V $ be nilpotent. Let $ f \in \mathbb{F[x]}. $ Show that $ f(T) $ is invertible iff $ f(0) \neq 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

**Theorem:** Let $ T: V \to V $ be nilpotent. Let $ f \in \mathbb{F[x]}. $ Show that $ f(T) $ is invertible iff $ f(0) \neq 0 $

**Attempt:**
$ ( \leftarrow )  $   Suppose that $ f(T) $ is invertible. Hence for every $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ $ ( f(T) )^n \neq 0 $. $ f(T) \neq 0 $ hence there exists $ v \in V $ s.t. $ f(T)v \neq 0  $. There exist $ a_0,...,a_k $ s.t. $ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 \cdot x + ... + a_k \cdot x^k $. Since $ T $ is nilpotent there exists $ q $ s.t. $ T^q =0  $ and $ T^{q-1} \neq 0 $
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $ f(0) = 0 $, thus $ a_0 =0 $ and  $ f(x) = a_1 \cdot x + ... + a_k \cdot x^k $.  $ f(T)v = a_1 \cdot T v + ... + a_k \cdot T^k v^k $. Operate on the last equation with $ T $ about $ q-2 $ times and we'll get $ T^{q-2}f(T)v = a_1 T^{q-1}v $. [ Now i'm stuck and don't know how to continue ].

$ ( \rightarrow ) $ Suppose $ f(0) \neq 0 $. We'll show that $ f(T) $ is invertible. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $ f(T) $ is invertible, hence there exists $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $ ( f(T) )^n =0 $ [ Now i'm stuck and don't know how to continue].

Can you please help me as to how to prove the above theorem?, I learned about eigenvalues but currently I'm studying a new section about nilpotency. I've seen related answers that involve eigenvalues and characteristic polynomial, but they're theorems are different than mine. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you know how the eigenvalues of $T$ and $f(T)$ are related? And do you know how to characterize invertibility in terms of the eigenvalues?

Comment: HInt: Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to express $\gcd(f(x),x^n)=a(x)f(x)+b(x)x^n$.

Comment: @EuYu Partly, but not in relation to nilpotency, if  $  \lambda  $ is eigenvalue of $ T $ then it is eigenvalue of $ f(T) $. I haven't learned any theorems that relate eigenvalues of $ T $ to its invertibility. I did learn however that if a transformation is diagonalizable then there exists a basis of eigenvectors/eigenspaces that span the vectorspace $ V $

Comment: @hazelnut_116 In that case, I would suggest a tangential exercise. Prove the following three results, each of which is of greater individual interest than your current problem. 1. Show that $T$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if $f(T)$ has eigenvalue $f(\lambda)$. 2. Show that $T$ is invertible if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue. 3. Show that an operator is nilpotent if and only if its only eigenvalue is $0$. There are probably faster ways to solve your exercise directly, but these three results will easily give you a solution, while at the same time being more insightful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ the smallest natural number such that $T^n = 0$

(->) Suppose that $f(T)$ invertible but $f(0) = 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$ we have $ f(x) = x q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. In particular $(f(x))^n= x^n(q(x))^n$ so $(f(T))^n = T^n(q(T))^n = 0$ and $f(T)$ is nilpotent so it can't be invertible : a contradiction.

(<-) Suppose that $f(0) \neq 0$ then

$$ f(T) = a_0I + T(a_1+a_2T+...+a_{n-1}T^{n-1})$$
where the second term is nilpotent. Now use the fact that if $A$ is nilpotent then $I+A$ is in invertible to finish the proof.

To see why this is the case, let $k$ be an odd number such that $A^k = 0$ and let $g(x) = 1+x^k$. Then $g$ has a root for $x = -1$
$$ g(x) = (1+x)p(x).$$
for some polynomial $p(x)$. Then
$$ g(A) = I+0 = (1+A)p(A)$$
so $(1+A)$ is invertible.

Comment: The last argument reads better as follows: $(I+A)p(A)=g(A) = I+A^k = I$